# Java Discord bot remains offline

Tags: java, gradle, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to create a Discord bot using *Java JDA* and *gradle*.I am trying to make it go online, but it doesn't work. I've tried to regenerate the token and to create another project. Nothing seems to work. I am using java 11 and don't have any error. What could cause this problem?

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile("net.dv8tion:JDA:4.2.0_168")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Main.java:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        JDA api = JDABuilder.createDefault("example").build();

        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
9:53:30 PM: Executing task...

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 785 ms

> Task :help

Welcome to Gradle 6.1.1.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

For troubleshooting, visit https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 17s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
9:53:57 PM: Task execution finished.
```

Comment: Have you tried [`JDA#awaitReady`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#awaitReady())?

Comment: Yes. Nothing changed.

Comment: You say "output" but for what is it the output? It looks like you're just running a gradle help task to me. To run the bot you need to use the run task or build a jar for it. Usually the IDE also has a run button right next to your main method.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I didn't push that button.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to create a JDABuilder with default settings. This can be done with the following code:

```
public class Bot {
    
 public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
     JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("<token from discord>")
            .addEventListeners(new BotListeners())
            .build();
 }
}
```

If you try switching out example for your actual token generated via the discord dev portal, this may bring your bot online. You can then look to implement an EventListener as follows:

```
// Must extend ListenerAdapter
public class BotListeners extends ListenerAdapter {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event) {

    if (!event.getAuthor().isBot()) {
        
        System.out.println("Hey, I have received a message!")
 }
}
```